# Unable to add XAML assembly reference for the assembly referenced in the project

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, prism, xml-namespaces

I have a Solution level project "Infrastructure.Interface" referenced in the "Application" project. But the XAML is not letting me to add a reference through xmlns i.e the Infrastructure.Interface is not getting listed in the drop down! Manually typing the details, i dont get the classes in it listed further in the XAML either!

Tried adding reference to a different solution level project and i am able to get that listed while adding a XAML xmlns reference! Not sure if its something i am missing here!

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: Do you get intellisense in code for that reference - i.e. is this only a problem in Xaml, or is any intellisense referencing that assembly broken? I've had this problem in the past where there exists a circular reference - i.e. does Infrastructure.Interface have a direct or indirect reference back to Application?

Comment: I do have intellisense in code! I am able to reference a namspace in Infrastructure.Interface but not this particular one. I Ended up solving it today by adding a XmlnsDefinition in the Assembly properties! the URL fr my namespace got listed in the XAML for the xmlns attribute!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up solving the issue by adding xmlnsdefinition for my namespaces . Still i dont know why i am not getting intellisense or getting compiler error while adding clr references, i was able to get around it using xmlnsdefinition. Any one with similar problem can give it a shot! And it looks cleaner too!

http://blog.pixelingene.com/2006/10/xmlnsdefinition-for-a-cool-namespace-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

I have had this problem before as well.  Once Closing and re-opening the solution fixed it, and a different time, building the solution again fixed it.  Still a different time, I found that if the Namespace is not in a different assembly, you don't have to annotate it as it doesn't do well when trying to find the local assembly by name.

Can you post the layout of your solution and the xmlns line you are trying?

Comment: i can describe, cant take the screen shot for the obvious reason! The structure is like "Infrastructure(solution folder) ->Infrastructure.Interface; Apps (solution Folder) -> MyApp"   I tried reopening the VSTS and rebuilding the solution already! hard luck!

Answer (score 0):

I found that unblocking the DLL's I was referencing explicitly made all the difference. If they've come from another machine, right click and "unblock". Reload VS and all was well.